# Usar INSERT despues de un DELETE o TRUNCATE

Tags: mysql

Tengo estas dos queries que por separado funcionan perfecto:

**Query 1:**

```
DELETE FROM table_2;
```

**Query 2:**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2
SELECT * from table_1;
```

Pero me sale un error cuando junto ambas query en una sola:

```
DELETE FROM table_2;
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2
SELECT * from table_1;
```

El error me dice:

`SQL Error: ... syntax error near 'INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2...`

Este error sale porque estoy usando un `INSERT` después de un `DELETE` o `TRUNCATE`, ¿cómo puedo insertar datos despues de eliminar todas las filas sin que ocurra este problema?. En caso que sea con `UPDATE`, ¿cómo sería su implementación?

Esto es en contexto de crear un stored procedure. Intenté escribir el código de las siguiente forma, pero da el mismo error:

```
START TRANSACTION;    
DELETE FROM table_2
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2
SELECT * from table_1;
COMMIT;
```

EDIT LO SOLUCIONÉ:

Puse esto mismo, pero en un stored procedure y funcionó. Cuando lo hacía desde un scrypt daba error.

```
DELETE FROM table_2;
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2
SELECT * from table_1;
```

Comment: No puedes hacer un insert mientras usas un delete

Comment: ¿Cómo quedaría entonces? Mi query va en borrar los datos de una tabla y luego volver a poner los datos ahí. Pensaba en usar `update`, pero no sé como hacer para que haga eso

Comment: Explica para qué es esto. Si es una normalización, ejecuta cada consulta por separado, si es para un código que va a funcionar continuamente, considera escribir un procedimiento almacenado, o resolverlo mediante TRIGGER o definiendo adecuadamente las restricciones de integridad referencial.

Comment: Listo, ahí añadí mas información en relación a lo que preguntaste.